# what is the difference between binary and binary coded decimal?

Tags: encoder

I'm studying encoders, which convert `decimal` to a code such as binary or binary coded decimal.  What is binary coded decimal?  Is it different from binary?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) is what "binary coded decimal" means. To find out what "binary" means follow the link to *binary* on the same page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows a distinct lack of research.  The topics are simple to look up on line.

Answer (score 5):

It's very late but I saw this so I thought I might answer. So binary coded decimal is a way to denote larger binary numbers in decimal form, except each digit is represented in binary for example.
1111(binary) = 15(decimal)
1111(binary) = 0001 0101(BCD)
so the bcd form of 1111 is two 4 bits numbers where the first 4 bit number in decimal is 1 and the second in decimal is 5, thus giving us 15. The way to calculate this is through an algorithm called double dabble.

Answer (score 2):

(B)inary (C)oded (D)ecimal data usage is found mostly in Assembler programs. On mainframes, it was mostly used to save half a byte, typically to allow an 8-digit date to be stored in a (four-byte) fullword as YYYYMMDD, avoiding a full binary conversion while also keeping the date more "eye friendly" format (i.e. easier to see in a file dump).
IBM Mainframe Assembler provides a special instruction - MVO: (M)o(V)e with (O)ffset - enabling very easy conversion from Packed Decimal (i.e. COMP-3 in COBOL) to BCD format (and vice-versa) without using an algorithm.

Example: Assume a date of 31-DEC-2017 in YYYYMMDD (8-byte) format is to be converted to a 8-digit BCD format field (4-bytes).
(1) Use the PACK instruction to convert the 8-char DATE into 5-bytes PACKED
(2) Use the MVO instruction to move the 8 significant binary decimal digits to the BCD field
[Note length override "...BCD(5)...": so sign X'F' from PACKED is shifted into byte *after* the BCD field]
BCD now contains X'20171231'

```
SAMPLE CSECT
       [...]
(1)    PACK PACKED,DATE     C'20171231'  BECOMES X'020171231F' IN PACKED
(2)    MVO  BCD(5),PACKED  X'020171231F' BECOMES  X'20171231'  IN BCD        
       [...]
BCD    DS   XL4
PACKED DS   PL5
DATE   DC   CL8'21071231'
```

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, to convert an 8-digit BCD date to an 8-char DATE is a simple sequence of 3 instructions:
(1) Insert sign into rightmost byte of a 5-byte packed decimal field
[think of this as restoring the sign shifted out in step 2 "MVO BCD(5),PACKED" in the first example, above]
(2) Use the MVO instruction to extract the 8 binary decimal digits into the 5-byte packed decimal field
(3) Use UNPK to convert the 5-byte packed decimal field to an 8-char date
DATE now contains C'20171231'

```
SAMPLE CSECT
       [...]
(1)    MVI  PACKED+(L'PACKED-1),X'0F' INSERT SIGN (PACKED BECOMES X'........0F'
(2)    MVO  PACKED,BCD   X'20171231'  BECOMES X'020171231F' IN PACKED    
(3)    UNPK DATE,PACKED X'020171231F' BECOMES  C'20171231'  IN DATE 
       [...]
BCD    DC XL4'20171231'  
PACKED DS PL5
DATE   DS CL8
```